# Semi supervised learning with sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, svm, outliers

I have a large multi dimensional unlabelled dataset of cars (price, mileage, horsepower, ...) for which I want to find outliers. I decided to use the sklearn OneClassSVM to build a decision boundary and have two main issues with my approach:

- My dataset contains a lot of missing values. Is there a way to make the svm classify the data with missing features as an inlier if any possible values for the missing features would be an inlier?
- I now want to add a feedback loop of manual moderated outliers. The manually moderated data should improve the classification of the SVM. I've read about the LabelSpreading model for semi-supervised learning. Would it be feasible to feed the classification output of the OneClassSVM to the LabelSpreading model and retrain this model when a sufficient amount of records are manually validated?

Answer (score 1):

For the first question. You could use an sklearn.preprocessing.imputer to impute the missing values by mean or median:

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.Imputer.html

You could add some boolean Features that recode if some of the other features had NaNs. So if you have features X_1, X_2 you add the boolean features

X_1_was_NaN and X_2_was_NaN

that are 1 if X_1==NaN or X_2==NaN. If X is your original pd.DataFrame you can create this by

```
 X = pd.DataFrame()
 # Create your features here 

 # Get the locations of the NaNs
 X_2 = 1.0 * X.isnull()

 # Rename columns
 X_2.rename(columns=lambda x: str(x)+"_has_NaN", inplace=True)

 # Paste them together
 X = pd.concat([X, X_2], axis=1)
```